# Why can't I see the inherited instance variable in subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, instance-variables

I have read in iOS Programming Fundamentals by Matt Neuberg that instance variables are protected, meaning that other classes, except for subclasses of this one, can't see them.

I have a parent class A where I define an ivar list.
(A.m)

```
@interface A ()

@end

@implementation A
{
     NSArray *list;
}

@end
```

Class B extends A (B.h)

```
#import "A.h"

@interface B:A

@end
```

(B.m)

```
@interface B ()

@end

@implementation B

list = 
...

@end
```

I want to use ivar list in child class B but the compiler doesn't see that the was reference declared in the parent class. I have tried explicitly using @protected but that doesn't work.  I don't want to expose ivar list on the public interface. It's an internal structure that is a common element of all subclasses. How can I do this?

Comment: You have to declare the instance variable in A.h so that B can see it, and you have to declare it as `@protected`

Answer (score 1):

Instance variables that are declared outside a class's public interface (in other words, the `@interface` section) are **private** by default. You can add a visibility modifier to the declaration to change the visibility of one or more ivars like so:

```
@implementation A
{
     NSNumber *_ivarWithDefaultVisibility;

@protected
     NSArray *_list;
     NSString *_anotherIvarWithProtectedVisibility;
}
```

(Note that according to Apple's Cocoa coding guidelines, ivar names should be prefixed with an underscore.)

Comment: This `@implementation` block is in the `A.m` file, so `B` won't be able to see it (the compiler doesn't have access to `A.m` when it's building `B.m`). You'd have to declare these ivars in the `@interface` block in `A.h` if you were going to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the usual way to implement protected properties in ObjC. (`@protected` and `@private` are very seldom used in Cocoa.) First, use a property, not an ivar. It will make it much cleaner. Declare it this way:

#### A.h

```
@interface A : NSObject
// Public interface goes here
@end
```

#### A.m

```
// Declare the property in a class extension inside the implementation file.
// This is the idiomatic way to create a "private" property.
@interface A ()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) NSArray *list;
@end
```

#### A+protected.h

```
// Enumerated any methods that should be accessible to subclasses here.
// Properties are just a special way of defining methods.
// The word "Protected" is just a category name.

@interface A (Protected)
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) NSArray *list;
@end
```

#### B.h

```
#import "A.h"   
@interface B : A
...
@end
```

#### B.m

```
#import "B.h"
#import "A+protected.h"

// ... now you can use self.list ...
```

This approach allows you to create any kind of "protected" method, not just properties, and is also the technique used to create "friend" classes.